# Connection to Bluez failed

Tags: ubuntu-mate, bluez

When I start Bluetooth Manager, I get this

```
Connection to Bluez failed.
bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue...
```

I tried re-installing bluez and blueman.

I have several dongles that I am trying to troubleshoot.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

sudo rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Try `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start` and see if it brings the daemon up.

Comment: @Parto [ ok ] Starting bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.service.

Comment: Does it solve the problem?

Comment: No, I still can not start bluetooth manager.

Comment: Does your computer have a physical wireless switch? You can try pressing it. There is a chance your wifi and bluetooth are hard blocked.

Comment: I do not understand what a physical wireless switch is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91070/discussion-between-fixit7-and-parto).

Comment: as of Ubuntu 20.04 (maybe earlier):

`systemctl enable bluetooth &&
systemctl start bluetooth` 
this will persist through reboots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently added a FitBit dongle. I decided to unplug it.

Bluetooth manager started without any error message.

Comment: Oh, cool. Weird that it affects bluetooth. Try running `sudo rfkill list` and see if you can see bluetooth in the list.

Comment: You can accept this answer, let me give you a +1, it has been an interesting question.

Answer (score 7):

Starting the `Bluetooth Manager` while bluetooth is disabled brings up this error message.

[image: Connection to BlueZ failed]

The fix is to start up the bluetooth service via terminal with the command below:

***NOTE:** Don't type the `$` in the command below, it is used to show the terminal prompt and the terminal response below it showing that bluetooth service has been started successfully.*

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
[ ok ] Starting bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.service.
```

Once the bluetooth service has been started, starting the `Bluetooth Manager` again brings this window up:

[image: Bluetooth turned off]

In which case, just press the `Enable Bluetooth` button to enable bluetooth and start the main window as seen below.

[image: Bluetooth Manager main window]

Finally, search and add your bluetooth devices using the `Search` button on the top left corner.

Comment: I did exactly what you posted. I still get the same message, Connection to Bluez failed. @Parto

Comment: @fixit7 Do you get any other error message? Give me some details I can work with

Comment: When I run it via system,preferences,hardware I get exactly this. Connection to BlueZ failed. Bluez daemon is not running, blueman manager can not continue. This probably means that there are no Bluetooth adaptors detected or Bluetooth damon was not started. And a Close box. I am doing my best to help you.

Comment: it is cool. Edit the question and include the output of `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status` and `sudo rfkill list`

Comment: See my posted answer. @Parto

Comment: I used `sudo service bluetooth start` instead of `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start`. Use of `service` seems more suitable for new linux versions.

Comment: I did this and it worked but only after doing a restart of my machine.