# How to fix my Bluetooth in Ubuntu?

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth in Ubuntu on a dual boot [Acer Aspire E5-521](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/search?q=Aspire%20E5-521&src=support) laptop fails with this message:   [image]

I also have Windows 10 at the same disk but with another partition and there the Bluetooth is working properly.

How can I get the Bluetooth work in Ubuntu?

EDIT 1

I try to type: `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start` in the Terminal
and I got: `sudo: /etc/init.d/bluetooth: command not found`

EDIT 2

Typing the command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` in the terminal I got the next output:

```
`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6645]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 06cb:2970 Synaptics, Inc. touchpad
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2c6e Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:2009 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub `
```

EDIT 3

I'm following the solution of: [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)

In step 7 checking if the file name is correct with the command: `dmesg | grep -i blue` I got the next message:

`[   23.906556] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
    [   23.906821] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    [   23.906827] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    [   23.906831] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    [   23.906854] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    [   24.034310] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
    [   24.035305] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
    [   24.051295] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
    [   24.051301] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
    [   24.074628] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
    [   24.074633] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
    [   26.321504] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
    [   26.322983] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003`

EDIT 4

It seems that the correct name for the .hcd file is BCM.hcd for my kernel 4.15.0-64-generic. Then after I shut down and and shut on my computer I get the following output for `dmesg | grep -i blue` command:

`[   23.041730] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   23.041765] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   23.041772] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   23.041776] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   23.041798] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   23.170312] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   23.171306] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   23.187310] Bluetooth: hci0: marin-Aspire-E5-521
[   23.187318] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0270
[   23.945369] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0270
[   23.962274] Bluetooth: hci0: Bluetooth USB module`

That solves the firmware problem of the driver for the Bluetooth. Thanks @Pilot6

But still I got the same error message at the beginning of this question. So I decide to try to use my Bluetooth trough the terminal. At the very first I found the following command:

`sudo service bluetooth start`

And that almost solve my problem; now I can use my Bluetooth properly in Ubuntu. But still remains a little issue: I need to run the above command every time I restart the computer in order to get working the Bluetooth.

EDIT 5 [AND THE SOLUTION]

I run the command: 
`sudo systemctl enable bluetooth`
That prevents that I have to run: `sudo service bluetooth start` every time I restart. 
But now the Bluetooth is always turned on! ( as expected I think) So I had kind of the opposite situation where I have to turn off the Bluetooth every time the Ubuntu starts to save battery energy when I do not need it. Thus I went to Startup Applications Preferences and uncheck the Bluetooth:
[image]

And that's it! That completely and finally fix my Bluetooth in Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you mean the build-in bluetooth utility? In that case yes I did and also didn't work.

Comment: I'm a newbie in ubuntu so I didn't use the Terminal I just click on the menu near the wifi icon. My PC is an Aspire E5-521 laptop.

Comment: Then you have not launched the daemon, which must be added to the Startup Applications list with `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start`

Comment: @K7AAY Here it is all the information of my Laptop https://pcel.com/Acer-NX-MPQAL-006-Laptop-Acer-E5-521-86J0-Procesador-AMD-A8-6410-hasta-2-4-GHz-Memoria-de-4-GB-DDR3-D-D-de-1-TB-Pantalla-LED-de-15-6-Video-RADEON-R5-Red-802-11b-g-n-Windows-110850

Comment: @K7AAY The terminal shows me the message: command not found when I typet your command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection to Bluez failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125657/connection-to-bluez-failed)

Comment: @Parto Unfortunely that did't solve my bluetooth problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the command you typed plus the output you got.

Comment: @Parto Sure, now my attempt  is above of EDIT 1.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Sure, I just did it.

Comment: Your BT device is `04ca:2009 Lite-On Technology Corp.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)

Comment: @Pilot6 I am following your solution at the "Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working".  Now I'm in step 7 in part "you can always check". And I got a message error. I will edit on the question.

Comment: Paste the message, select it and click the `{}` soft button to format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99357/discussion-between-pilot6-and-jose-marin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
```

That will enable the service on startup.

Comment: Thank you Pilot6! That solves the issue of type the command `sudo service bluetooth start` every time I restart the OS. It remained a last little thing but I can handled by myself. This was a work for the last night and today. I Will edit the question with the final solution and I will give you the check for the answer. I really appreciate your help and the other members of the community.